# Is there a better way to achieve this CSS animation without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Just experimenting with a loading bar. The primary issue is, once each bar is done with its iteration, it needs to start again on top of the last bar. I did this via some hacky JS but maybe there's a more clever way to do it using pure CSS?

**HTML**

```
<div class="loading-bar">
    <div class="bar"><div class="bar-inner"></div></div>
    <div class="bar"><div class="bar-inner"></div></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.loading-bar {
    clear: both;
    height: 12px;
    width: 100%;

    position: relative;

    .bar {
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 12px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        z-index: 0;

        .bar-inner {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 0;
            height: 12px;            
            -webkit-animation-name: loadbars;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
        }

        &:nth-child(1) .bar-inner {
            background: gray;            
        }
        &:nth-child(2) .bar-inner {
            background: blue;
            -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
        }             
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes loadbars {
    0% { width: 0; }

    50% { width: 100%; }

    100% { width: 100%; }
}
```

**JS**

```
var bars = $(".bar-inner");
var zindex = 1;
var listener = function () {
    zindex++;
    $(this).parent().css("z-index", zindex);    
};

bars.on("webkitAnimationIteration", listener);
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/18uqrtxo/

### Updated

I've updated the demo to show pure CSS with 4 bars, just for fun.

http://jsfiddle.net/18uqrtxo/2/

Comment: He's already using keyframes.   @OP what are you wanting to acheive. It looks like you already have a non-JS solution with CSS Animations ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Animate the `z-index`.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/18uqrtxo/1/)

Apply the `z-index` to the bars, not their containers. This will allow the bar to be on top when it's getting wider, and underneath when it's at full width.

Comment: Awesome! I tried doing that but must have missed something since it wasn't working. Thanks!

Comment: If there are more than 2 bars, would your approach change?

Comment: It would get a little more complicated as you need to ensure that the z-index is appropriate along each part of the animation, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: You're right! Just need to add `n + 1` parts of the animation for the bars you need and count down the z-index.

Comment: With this you could probably get away with a single element and use pseudo element keyframe animations. Although, I have only used css and not scss, so I can't say if there would be an easier way